# Background Image is displayed OK at design time but compiler throws exception at runtime (when debugging)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

This problem makes me confused. I simply set `Background` of my `Window` to an `ImageBrush` all using `Properties` window at design time. First, I add a `JPG` image to my `Resources` (Double-click on Resources -> Select Images -> Add Existing File ...). Then I select my `Window`, open `Properties` window to select `ImageSource` for the `Background` property. It shows the image OK at that time. But when running the application, it throws the exception:
**'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '75' and line position '10**

I don't understand this exception well, searching with Goolge won't help much because there are many various exceptions (inner exception) can throw this. In my case the inner exception is **Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Ellipse button with Animation\bin\Debug\Resources\back_ground.jpg'**.

The strangest thing is it shows the image OK at design time, but at run time, that exception is thrown.

Do you have any idea to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Clean the solution and build again

Comment: @rapsalands I've done what you suggested but it doesn't work.

Comment: similar query, below link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617086/imagebrush-throws-exception-when-trying-to-set-window-background?rq=1

Comment: Try to set "Copy to out put directory" property of the file to the "Copy always" value

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh thank you very much, that's what I missed. In fact, the `Build Action` doesn't need to be `Resource`, I'm letting it as `None` (by default). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set "Copy to out put directory" property of the file to the "Copy always" value

Comment: I know you gave the suggestion first and helped me out. So this answer is worth being accepted. Thanks. BTW, maybe `tanuj_loop` was a little late for his update but I still want to give both of you 1 up-vote.

Comment: Thanks :) 5 more symbols

Answer (score 1):

hey KingBoy the problem is related to the **properties** that you have set for your image..right now your image property is set to **DesignTime**.So make it to **Content** and **Copy Always** Everything will just work fine.you can do this by click on your image and then set its properties in property Window..hope it helps you..

Comment: sorry but changing it to whatever doesn't seem to work. With my search before, I found some suggestion doing so (change the `Build Action` of my image to `Resource`) but it couldn't help.

Comment: in fact, I've read the suggestion of `ViacheslavSmityukh` before and tried it. it works now.